# signal SIGABRT Error when trying to assign text for uitextfield

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

when I try assign text for UItextfield, it make my app crash.
here is the image:
[image]

But when I comment the code line: `txtExpire.text = posCustomer.CCExpire;` and `txtExpire.text = posSupplier.CCExpire;` my app work OK. Please help me find out the root cause.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
     @synchronized (self){
         if (posCustomer) {
             txtAccountLimit.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[posCustomer.AccountLimit intValue]];
             txtBSB.text = posCustomer.BankBSB;
             txtAccount.text = posCustomer.BankAccount;
             txtNotes.text = posCustomer.BankNotes;
             txtCreditCardNo.text = posCustomer.CCNumber;
             txtNameOnCard.text = posCustomer.CCName;
             txtExpire.text = posCustomer.CCExpire;
         }else if (posSupplier){
             txtAccountLimit.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[posSupplier.AccountLimit intValue]];
             txtBSB.text = posSupplier.BankBSB;
             txtAccount.text = posSupplier.BankAccount;
             txtNotes.text = posSupplier.BankNotes;
             txtCreditCardNo.text = posSupplier.CCNumber;
             txtNameOnCard.text = posSupplier.CCName;
             txtExpire.text = posSupplier.CCExpire;
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Turn on Exception Breakpoint(s) if you haven't yet.

Comment: May be you are getting `nil` value for `posCustomer.CCExpire`.

Comment: data type mismatch or assigning

Comment: Add your crash report in your question, its not clear

Comment: what data type CCExpire

Comment: What data type is posCustomer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your stack trace, it looks as though you are trying to assign an `NSDate` to a `textField.text` which is a string. Specifically, it looks as though `CCExpire` is an `NSDate` and not an `NSString`.

If that is the case, you will need an [NSDateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to convert the date to a string.

Comment: CCExpire is a string, But into my data base it's datetime type.So it's reason for my app crash when i get from the database and use it as a string. A stupid mistake.Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like posCustomer.CCExpire is a NSDate object. Therefore you cannot use it as a NSString (the class expected by the text property of a UITextField). You should either use posCustomer.CCExpire.description (kind of bad practice but it works) or use a NSDateFormatter for example :

`txtExpire.text = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:posCustomer.CCExpire dateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle timeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];`

Answer (score -1):

IMO, the problem isn't in assigning text.
As per the logs shown, you are trying to call `[NSDate length]` (Not sure where you call it, but probably in `CCExpire` getter).

Please revise that getter method or post it here so we can help you more.

Comment: When setting the text property to a label, the label needs to draw the text. In order to do so, it called a bunch of method on its text property including length. If you pass a NSDate (like in this scenario) or any other class that is not kind of NSString, you'll get a unknown selector send to instance exception at some point